# gpg-agent problems on Manjaro Linux (KDE)

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, kwallet

Recently Github announced support for signed commits, so I configured Git:

```
git config --global user.signingkey F03CB372
git config --global commit.gpgsign true
```

I already had a GPG key `F03CB372`, looks like I've created it soon after installing the OS. It is used somewhere by KWallet.

But when I try to commit and sign I get this error:

```
$ git commit -S -m 'Signed commit'
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

No KDE popup asks me for a pass-phrase..

I overcome this with `killall gpg-agent && gpg-agent --daemon`. I need to restart my agent after each reboot, once per session, first time I use it. `killall` is here because actually I usually have `gpg-agent` somehow running, but looks like it is a misconfigured instance. After that KDE asks me for a pass-phrase and I get my commits signed.

Also, looks like other programs suffer from this too. I don't use KWallet much, but, for example, Amarok stores my Last.FM account there. I use it very rarely, but I've noticed that scrobbling (which needs the account) doesn't work until I restart `gpg-agent` too.

Here is what I have in `~/.gnugpg`:

```
gpg.conf
openpgp-revocs.d
private-keys-v1.d
pubring.kbx
pubring.kbx~
random_seed
S.gpg-agent
S.uiserver
trustdb.gpg
```

As you see, I don't have any `gpg-agent.conf` there, but this is the default setup. Maybe this is the problem?